# json.net problems with null

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This my code

```
JObject test = JObject.Parse(auth_id);
                 string access_token = (string)test["access_token"];
    string user_id = (string)test["user_id"];
    string error = (string)test["error"];
```

This is my json code

```
{"access_token":"0533","expires_in":0,"user_id":1}
```

What did I do wrong?

Error was: check error may be null

I had  an idea on how to make the code better. Error with null go away. But now all the  variables are empty.

```
string error = "";
     string user_id = "";
     string access_token = "";
     access_token = ((string)test["access_token"]) == null ? access_token : "";
     user_id = ((string)test["user_id"]) == null ? user_id : "";
     error = ((string)test["error"]) == null ? error : "";
```

Comment: {"access_token":"0533","expires_in":0,"user_id":1} - Where are you passing in error?

Comment: Could you try `test["access_token"] as string` instead? I don't understand exactly the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your code backwards... You want:

```
string error = "";
string user_id = "";
string access_token = "";
access_token = ((string)test["access_token"]) == null ? "" : (string)test["access_token"];
user_id = ((string)test["user_id"]) == null ? "" : (string)test["user_id"];
error = ((string)test["error"]) == null ? "" : (string)test["error"];
```

Edited: You were pulling the variables you had just defined.  So it will ALWAYS be empty.

You want to assign the request variables if it's not null.